# Python grid for a game with mapping

Tags: python

I am required to write a function that makes python display a grid. The grid needs to have rows labelled A, B, C - Z respectively dependant on user input for grid size and columns labelled 1, 2, 3. Where there are cells A1, A2, A3 and so on. Ask any questions it's a little bit difficult to explain. it would look kind of like this:
The '~' represents uncovered cells and I would need to map the "~'s" to `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2` respectively.

```
__1__2__3_
A|~ | ~| ~ |
B| ~| ~| ~ |
C| ~| ~| ~ |
```

Answer (score 0):

following code works fine:

```
rows = 3
c0 = "__"
c1 = "A|"
c2 = "B|"
c3 = "C|"
for i in range(rows):
    c0=c0+str(i+1)+"_"
    c1=c1+"~|"
    c2=c2+"~|"
    c3=c3+"~|"
print(c0)
print(c1)
print(c2)
print(c3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    outputList = []
    numColumns = 10
    charactersPerCell = 2

    for i in range ( ord( 'A' ), ord( 'Z' ) + 1 ):

        outputRow = []

        for j in range( numColumns ):
            outputRow.append( '|' + str( chr( i ) ) + str( j ) )
        outputList.append( outputRow )

    for row in outputList:

        # add one for | delimiting character.
        print( '-' * ( numColumns * ( charactersPerCell + 1 ) + 1 ) )

        for col in row:
            print( col, end = '' )

        print( '|' )

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|A0|A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6|A7|A8|A9|                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|B0|B1|B2|B3|B4|B5|B6|B7|B8|B9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|C0|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|C7|C8|C9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|D0|D1|D2|D3|D4|D5|D6|D7|D8|D9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|E0|E1|E2|E3|E4|E5|E6|E7|E8|E9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|F0|F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8|F9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|G0|G1|G2|G3|G4|G5|G6|G7|G8|G9|
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|H0|H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6|H7|H8|H9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|I0|I1|I2|I3|I4|I5|I6|I7|I8|I9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|J0|J1|J2|J3|J4|J5|J6|J7|J8|J9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|K0|K1|K2|K3|K4|K5|K6|K7|K8|K9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|L0|L1|L2|L3|L4|L5|L6|L7|L8|L9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|M0|M1|M2|M3|M4|M5|M6|M7|M8|M9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|N0|N1|N2|N3|N4|N5|N6|N7|N8|N9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------
|O0|O1|O2|O3|O4|O5|O6|O7|O8|O9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|P0|P1|P2|P3|P4|P5|P6|P7|P8|P9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|Q0|Q1|Q2|Q3|Q4|Q5|Q6|Q7|Q8|Q9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|R0|R1|R2|R3|R4|R5|R6|R7|R8|R9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|S0|S1|S2|S3|S4|S5|S6|S7|S8|S9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|T0|T1|T2|T3|T4|T5|T6|T7|T8|T9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------
|U0|U1|U2|U3|U4|U5|U6|U7|U8|U9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|V0|V1|V2|V3|V4|V5|V6|V7|V8|V9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|W0|W1|W2|W3|W4|W5|W6|W7|W8|W9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|X0|X1|X2|X3|X4|X5|X6|X7|X8|X9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|Y0|Y1|Y2|Y3|Y4|Y5|Y6|Y7|Y8|Y9|                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|Z0|Z1|Z2|Z3|Z4|Z5|Z6|Z7|Z8|Z9|
```